# See connected signals for instantiated Node while in Debug mode

Tags: debugging, gdscript, godot-4

I'm trying to debug an issue with my game, where the function that should be connected to a signal is not being called. I have a created minimal repro of the situation by:

1. Create a fresh Godot 4 project
2. Create a `Thing` scene with `StaticBody2D` node (with sprite and square collision shape) and a `Thing.gd` script:

   ```
   extends StaticBody2D

   func _on_input_event(viewport, event, shape_idx):
       if event is InputEventMouseButton and event.button_index == MOUSE_BUTTON_LEFT:
         modulate = Color(1,1,0,1) if event.is_pressed() else Color(1,1,1,1)
   ```

   The `_on_input_event` function is connected to the `input_event` signal of the `StaticBody2D`.
3. Creating a `Root` `Node2D` node with a `Root.gd` script:

   ```
   extends Node2D

   var thing_scene = preload("res://Thing.tscn")

   func _ready():
       var other_thing = thing_scene.instantiate()
       other_thing.position = Vector2(200, 200)
       add_child(other_thing)
   ```
4. Set a break point at that last line of code
5. Run the `Root` node in debug mode
6. When the breakpoint hits, click "Locals" => "other_thing"'s Object ID to open the Inspector

At this point I *can* see the *properties* of the Node, like so:

[image: Godot editor in debug mode showing the Inspector window highlighted]

My problem is that I see *nothing* if I then click on the "Node" tab next to "Inspector", it will just say:

> Select a single node to edit its signals and groups

Here's a screenshot of that:

[image: Godot editor in debug mode showing quote from above]

What I was *hoping* to see is the same thing I see when *not* running in Debug mode and selecting the to-be-instantiated scene's `StaticBody2D` node:

[image: Godot editor in edit mode showing the connected signals]

In my sample / repro above the signal *is* working because I can observe the function's effects. In my actual game the signal is *not* working, which is why I'm looking for a way to debug that situation. I want to know if the signal is connected at all, or if something else is causing my issues.

Bottom line: How can I check connected signals for a component created with `instantiate()` while debugging?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm unaware of a way to see the connected signals of a `Object` in runtime in the debugger.

You could select the `Node` in the "Scene" in the "Local" tab while the game is running, but that will only show you the signals connected in design. I mean, it is not looking at the `Node`s in runtime. You can see at the `Node`s in runtime using the "Remote" tab, but then it won't show the signals.

---

Instead, we could check the connections form code. To see what is connected to an `Object` do this:

```
for signal_description in signal_source.get_signal_list():
    var signal_name := str(signal_description["name"])
    var connections := signal_source.get_signal_connection_list(signal_name)
    for connection in connections:
        prints(connection)
```

Or to see what is connected to an `Object` do this:

```
for connections in signal_target.get_incoming_connections():
    for connection in connections:
        prints(connection)
```

---

Regardless, about the issue you are trying to debug… You don't need to connect the `"input_event"` signal from the `StaticBody2D` to itself, instead you can override the virtual method `_input_event`.

---

Finally, about the source of your issue… Following your instructions you didn't set `input_pickable` to `true`. It defaults to `false` in Godot 4.

You need to set `input_pickable` to `true` for either the `"input_event"` signal or the virtual method `_input_event` to work. **Addendum**: Inside of a `Viewport` (either `SubViewport` or `Window`) you also need to set `physics_object_picking` to `true`.

This is likely the source of the issue.

*Note: `"input_event"` and `_input_event` also don't work if the `collision_layer` property is empty (i.e. `0` - it defaults to `1`).*

---

By the way, be aware that, based on your first picture, you have added an instance of `Thing` in `Root` in the editor. And you are also adding another instance of `Thing` from the code in `_ready`. So there will be two instances in runtime.

You also want to make sure the positions and dimensions of the collision shape are what you expect. You can enable "Visible Collision Shapes" in the "Debug" menu so Godot renders the collision shapes in the running game.

Comment: Cheers! PS. I suggest tweaking the snippets, first one to `prints(connection)` (without `...s`), and second one to `for key in connections:` and `prints(key, "=>", connections[key])`. Either way, they got me in the right direction and answer the question I asked!

Comment: All the other tips are once again educational and helpful! Some of them were _part_ of the problem, and for future visitors additionally you may have (like I did) a `SubViewport` in the mix which needs `Physics` => `Objects Picking` also turned on for all of it to work.